# Monterey 12.2 WPA2 Enterprise not connecting

Tags: network, wifi, security

We have having major issues connecting users to our University Wi-Fi network.
The devices are  MacBook with both Intel & Apple Silicon.
Our radius server indicates that a successful connection has been made however the end user gets the standard 'move closer to the router' error message.
We have deleted Wi-Fi certs from the login keychain access and also the Wi-Fi preferences plist but still no connections being made.
We have no Wi-Fi issues with a multitude of Catalina & Big Sur MacBooks however Monterey is proving difficult
Has anybody else experienced similar issues ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/smohaq/monterey_122_wpa2_enterprise/hwd9py2/

Comment: Did you ever fix this Michael? I have just sent a bug report to Apple using Feedback Assistant. Not sure if they will ever read that though...

Comment: No just had another user with an 2021 intel MacBook Pro updated from 12.1 to 12.2.1 still did not resolve the issue very frustrating

Comment: Turns out it is McAfee Endpoint Security that was causing the problem. If you are not running 10.7.8 compatible with Monterey it will stop services such a Wi-Fi and VPN from working.

Comment: Eh too bad, we're not running any AV currently. I'll have to keep nagging Apple about it I guess.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Only happens with some M1 Pro (16" and 14"), other models of the same make are fine. We have Cisco AP's with ISE. The auth-request never reaches the ISE, cert-exchange fails seemingly (as per the Wifi-Controller logs).
macOS 12.1, 12.2, 12.2.1 and 12.3 beta.